# Limit to the number of values I can specify in a query

Tags: azure-table-storage

I want to select a certain number of rows from a table in my Azure Table Storage by specifying the PartitionKey and RowKey. Say, I have a list of 500 PartitionKey and RowKey pairs that I need to read from my table. Can I specify these 500 values in my query?

I have a feeling that I'll have to come up with a composite key as my partition key so that I don't have to specify so many PartitionKey/RowKey values but I want to first make sure that there's a limit to the number of values I can specify in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a limit to the number of values that can be returned in a query. Check out the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx